# I want to use dotnet restore command in "Execute Windows batch command" in my jenkins job but i am getting error

Tags: jenkins, dll, console-output, dotnet-restore, dotnet-build

This is what i have put in "executr windows batch command" -

"dotnet restore
"C:\Users\nraut.SIPL.jenkins\workspace\WebNetAgentSln\WCFServiceGX.sln"
dotnet build "C:\Users\nraut.SIPL.jenkins\workspace\WebNetAgentSln\WCFServiceGX.sln" /t:rebuild /property:Configuration=Release  /p:GenerateSerializationAssemblies=Off"

This is part of console output -

[C:\Users\nraut.SIPL.jenkins\workspace\WebNetAgentSln\WebNetAgent\WebNetAgent.csproj]
C:\Users\nraut.SIPL.jenkins\workspace\WebNetAgentSln\WebNetAgent\CommonClass\PickupDetail.cs(54,23): warning CS0414: The field 'PickupDetail.formatString' is assigned but its value is never used [C:\Users\nraut.SIPL.jenkins\workspace\WebNetAgentSln\WebNetAgent\WebNetAgent.csproj]
C:\Users\nraut.SIPL.jenkins\workspace\WebNetAgentSln\WebNetAgent\NetShipService.cs(87,29): warning CS0414: The field 'NetagentService.iFlightStatusService' is assigned but its value is never used [C:\Users\nraut.SIPL.jenkins\workspace\WebNetAgentSln\WebNetAgent\WebNetAgent.csproj]
C:\Users\nraut.SIPL.jenkins\workspace\WebNetAgentSln\WebNetAgent\NetagentService.cs(1879,107): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'isAgentService' of 'OperationServiceClient.FinalEndRoute(int, DateTime, ref JSONToken, out FaultContract, string)' [C:\Users\nraut.SIPL.jenkins\workspace\WebNetAgentSln\WebNetAgent\WebNetAgent.csproj]
23 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:05.13

C:\Users\nraut.SIPL.jenkins\workspace\WebNetAgentSln-build>exit 1
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

I was expecting that after putting in dotnet restore command in "execute windows batch command" it will update all the dependencies and required dll files when i run the jenkins job.

Comment: This seems to be the actual error stopping the program: `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'isAgentService' of 'OperationServiceClient.FinalEndRoute(int, DateTime, ref JSONToken, out FaultContract, string)`. Maybe something wrong with the code?

Comment: The code is working fine. I want jenkins job to update all dll files by using dotnet restore

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
            bat '"%msbuild%" "%WORKSPACE%\\app.sln" /p:autoparameterizationwebconfigconnectionstrings=false /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:PackageLocation="%WORKSPACE%\\deployment\\app-%buildName%.zip"'
```

%something% is how bat shell interpolates variables.

this is an exmaple, i could do the same with dotnet restore/rebuid command too. The required dependecies/libraries must be available on the agent machine.

Comment: Can i use the command which you have provided to update the dll dependecies/libraries automatically?

Comment: Definitely, something like this maybe:
```
 bat '"%nuget%" restore app.sln -configfile %nugetconfig% '
```
Put the nuget config file in your managed files or you could fetch it from the repo itself, this should work to resolve your dependencies/libraries

Comment: if possible can you please explain what you instructed in a simple way??